# xslt is it ok if we do `select="$position + $jump"`?

Tags: xml, xslt

I've got this code (which is working properly):

```
 <xsl:template name="CamelChain">
      <xsl:param name="input"/>
      <xsl:param name="position"/>
      <xsl:if test="$position &lt;= string-length($input)">
         <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="substring($input, $position, 1) = '_'">
            <xsl:value-of select="translate(substring($input, $position + 1, 1), 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')"/>

            <xsl:call-template name="CamelChain">
               <xsl:with-param name="input" select="$input"/>
               <xsl:with-param name="position" select="$position + 2"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
         </xsl:when>

         <xsl:otherwise>

            <xsl:value-of select="substring($input, $position, 1)"/>

            <xsl:call-template name="CamelChain">
               <xsl:with-param name="input" select="$input"/>
               <xsl:with-param name="position" select="$position + 1"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
         </xsl:otherwise>
         </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:if>
   </xsl:template>
```

And i attempted to normalize it abit as such:

```
   <xsl:template name="CamelChain">
      <xsl:param name="input"/>
      <xsl:param name="position"/>
      <xsl:if test="$position &lt;= string-length($input)">
         <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="substring($input, $position, 1) = '_'">
               <xsl:value-of select="translate(substring($input, $position + 1, 1), 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')"/>
               <xsl:variable name="jump" select="2"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
               <xsl:value-of select="substring($input, $position, 1)"/>
               <xsl:variable name="jump" select="1"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
         </xsl:choose>
         <xsl:call-template name="CamelChain">
            <xsl:with-param name="input" select="$input"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="position" select="$position + $jump"/>
         </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:if>
   </xsl:template>
```

But after I've "normalized" it.. it's not working anymore. I suspect its got something to do with the `select="$position + $jump"` portion but i'm not sure what's wrong with it. does anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: Don't say that something "doesn't work". Tell us how it fails. The first thing you need when debugging someone's code is to know the error messages.

Comment: well its working but not working as expected.. so i'd get no error messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your two `$jump` variables each go out of scope before you reference them**.

In XSLT as in any block-structured language a variable has a scope, out of which it is undefined.

```
    <xsl:when test="substring($input, $position, 1) = '_'">
        <xsl:value-of select=
        "translate(substring($input, $position + 1, 1),
                   'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
                   'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="jump" select="2"/>
    </xsl:when>
```

here you are defining the `$jump` variable at the very end of its scope and it immediately ceases to exist. This is an obvious error and Some XSLT processors as Saxon even issue a warning message about this.

You have exactly the same problem with the other variable (also named `$jump`) definition.

Comment: is it true its scope is everything within its parent. i.e. its children + its siblings?

Comment: @Pacerier: Yes. I think you'll benefit from reading a good book on XSLT.

Comment: definitely i'd plan to asaic. but right now i'm under pressure to quickly hack some stuff out

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that the variable `$jump` is out of scope. You can't set variables inside a `xsl:choose`, and expect their value to persist outside. I believe you have to edit the middle section like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="char" select="substring($input, $position, 1)" />

<xsl:variable name="jump">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$char = '_'">2</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>1</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$char = '_'">
        <xsl:value-of select="translate(substring($input, $position + 1, 1), 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$char"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>

<xsl:call-template name="CamelChain">
    <xsl:with-param name="input" select="$input"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="position" select="$position + $jump"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

The `xsl:choose` must go within the `xsl:variable`, not the other way around.

To be honest though, I can't see anything objectionable with your original code. It looks cleaner to me.

Comment: well compared to this solution, the `Part 1` code of my question is cleaner of course.. since this repeats the `substring($input, $position, 1)`. However comparing `Part 2` to `Part 1`, part two is way cleaner (well assuming if it did worked of course)

Comment: @Pacerier: Store that in the variable then! `<xsl:variable name="char" select="substring($input, $position, 1)" />`

Comment: you are missing my point.. `Part 2` is cleaner than `Part 1` because we do not have to repeat  `<xsl:call-template name="CamelChain">` neither do we have to repeat
            `<xsl:with-param name="input" select="$input"/>` neither do we have to repeat
            `<xsl:with-param name="position" select="$x"/>` (all of which are repeated in `Part 1 Code`
       )